# Можно ли на c++ работать с unity?

Tags: c++, unity3d

Можно ли на c++ работать с unity?

Comment: При большом желании можно. Однако целесообразность такой затеи сомнительна.

Comment: Тогда почему на ней уже написаны тысячи игр?